# Gmail mails fetching with oauth

Tags: php, email, gmail

http://appdeal.com/appDeal/getmail2.php

I am trying to fetch the email.

I Have to do that when someone register in my website with their email. Then they link the email with my website using the Gmail oath. Then I have to use these oath token to read their mails after some interval and parse these mails to get some important text from the email in the  form of HTML, So I parse this easily using XPATH.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please show us some code and describe in detail what you try to achieve / what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For **fetching the e-mails**, you have basically two options:

Either you use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) or you do that by using a service like [Context.IO](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).

If you use Context.IO, you can also access other inboxes and not just GMail. If you work with the Gmail API, make sure that you ask for offline access when getting the oAuth token, otherwise you won't be able to pull e-mails at a later point in time. Fetching the e-mails directly via IMAP in PHP seems to be quite complex.

When it comes to actually **parsing the e-mails**, please keep in mind that the HTML of e-mails is not always accurate and your XPath method will fail when there are slight changes in the layout. Out of experience (I'm the founder of [mailparser.io](http://mailparser.io)) I would suggest you rely on text patterns for the parsing. Search for things you can identify like "Order ID:" with regular expressions for example.

Comment: I used the gmail api but in that i dont get the exact html. so its so difficult to get the specific data... is there any third party api  that is user for fecting the mails

Comment: can u tell me more about Context.IO  how its work some example

Comment: never tried context.IO myself so far. I'm surprised that the Gmail API doesn't give you the original HTML.

Comment: the gmail api provide the data which is to complex. and i need every time different data. like in first mail there is one item with name and price  and in second time the item number change..

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there

Comment: what is mean by afraid ??